# React Recoil "Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never[]"?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, recoiljs

I'm following the [React Recoil Todo List tutorial](https://recoiljs.org/docs/basic-tutorial/atoms), but for some reason their are type errors when following the tutorial and I'm unsure how to satisfy them correctly.

Here is the code:

```
export const todoListAtom = atom({
  key: 'todoListAtom',
  default: [],
});
```

```
export function TodoItem({item}: {item: TodoItem}) {
  const [todoList, setTodoList] = useRecoilState(todoListAtom);
  const index = todoList.findIndex((listItem) => listItem === item);

  const editItemText = ({target: {value}}) => {
    const newList = replaceItemAtIndex(todoList, index, {
      ...item,
      text: value,
    });

    setTodoList(newList);
  };
```

The type of setTodoList is:

```
const setTodoList: (valOrUpdater: never[] | ((currVal: never[]) => never[])) => void
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is what you're looking for. Some of your code is missing, so I created stand-ins for the missing parts:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwIYwiANHArgZwKYBKeAxhMADYDKMKeAvnAGZRpwDkUJZ5bA3ALAAoITACeYPHAAqEACYQAkjDwg4AXkRC4cZQA8YALjg4YUYADsA5gMF0bQxlnPEYwCObicw5JMTxKVAEEYBXNZPF04AB4pAD4ACiQoKCRRIykAbQBdTAtw3SNzLBAAIzwoTHM8AHcANSRyLDx0gEp07M1BbU4YLCgPJJTRADoQJDB4+IA3BqbclvVYuGB1NQ08iLgAfjgqutnJIxnGvBabOiEhCMhYOFJzEx05CAAZYBNg1g0UNBjngJA2QSCC0cAA1ng0uxUPI3h9UCA2OhQeFGEgsORDHBssjbGdLoJrtB4I5nK53NJ-soQPEEMBqXQjHTqekqSo6AsQV07u5HhkYa93jBMPgYDJYUKsupsPgiKQKNRaPEBXCYJ8QPjufdHhtIhoVULhow8qF8pNyEKAQs1EsLSYAat1tTNaDtfA8LJ6QCpBF4BpaTQoJY8FiEMcmnRGYhA8HQ+HmsZTBZLJHrUsudptG7djVVdKvD4-ADgqaIsrnqrcmEIpgM5ntMNG-SVLj69o9Fj463Mxz7NztKLxYKTPE9qrNdo7ATtAB6GdwRvDIQXQRAA)

```ts
import {atom, useRecoilState} from 'recoil';

type TodoItem = {
  text: string;
};

function replaceItemAtIndex <T>(array: T[], index: number, newValue: T): T[] {
  return array.map((value, i) => i === index ? newValue : value);
}

export const todoListAtom = atom<TodoItem[]>({
  key: 'todoListAtom',
  default: [],
});

export function TodoItem({item}: {item: TodoItem}) {
  const [todoList, setTodoList] = useRecoilState(todoListAtom);
  const index = todoList.findIndex((listItem) => listItem === item);

  const editItemText = ({target: {value}}: {target: {value: string}}) => {
    const newList = replaceItemAtIndex(todoList, index, {
      ...item,
      text: value,
    });

    setTodoList(newList);
  };

  // ...
}
```